# Magento 1.4.1.1 - Order numbers are used twice

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

we have a problem, where we don't really know how to tackle it.

very, very seldom (once a month with hundreds of orders) a customer get's an order number assigned to his order, which has been used months ago by a completely different customer, with a completely different cart.

the customer (and we in copy) get the verification email, so at least we can recreate the order, but we can't find the order in the backend, or, to be specific, we find the order number, but it is assigned to a months old order.

Has someone an idea how to start to track this problem in the light, that it happens so seldom?

PAT

Comment: have you ever deleted any test orders from your cart?

Comment: I fear yes, but with one of the extensions that offer this, and it is not the number which got reused

Comment: Take a look at your `sales_flat_order` table in the database, is it the `increment_id` or the `entity_id` that is being duplicated? Magento keeps a separate auto_increment value of entity_id that should prevent such.

Comment: ok: http://i.imgur.com/ojxox.png

1561 is the order ID as it was given to the new order (we know this from the email)

the amount of the order tells me, that 1561 is the entity_id

what can I do with this information? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, this was a really dumb mistake on our side. we had a staging server open in the internet, which wasn't in the google index but some users found it anyway. they ordered on this staging server, the emails got to the actual sales person but the order number was from the staging server, not the production server. so, no magento bug here..